# How to check if a number falls in a given range

Tags: php, logic

I have a variable `$user_id` (number value)

Want to check if `$user_id` falls in between the range of 1 - 1000 or 1001 - 2000 or 2001 - 3000 .... 99001 - 100000

1. Is there a way to do this without writing 100 `switch` or `if` statements in PHP?
2. When it finds the match, execute a code.

I know while and for loops are required for this. But not able to code it properly.

Comment: "_Is there a way to do this without writing 100 switch or if statements in PHP?_" That entirely depends on what you are planning to do with this range. If the code executed is completely different depending on the range, than switches/if-s might be your best bet.

Comment: "_while and for loops are required for this_"  -- incorrect, you should certainly not use a loop since the range can be determined through a one-time mathematical expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the simplest way:

```
    $check = 0;
    $nextCheck = $check+1001;
    while ($check < 100001) {
    If ($user_id > $check && $user_id < $nextCheck) {
      // Code ...
      break;
    } else {
       $check+=1000;
       $nextCheck+=1000;
    }
    }
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: I would not use this code in one of my projects.  Iterating upto 1000 times is needless work.

Comment: I think it's 100 loop not 1000.

Comment: And unfortunately I didn't ask you to use my code in all your project.

Comment: Yes.  You are right, it is 100 needless iterations, my mistake.  Your answer still lacks its educational explanation.  A `for()` loop would have better readability.

Comment: Right, I should use for() loop in the code above. It's will be more practice. I agree with that.

Comment: @Hida : Your code is something that I was looking for. But It stops functioning when $user_id is > 1000. But I managed with a minor tweak. 

I Added      
"$check+=1000; 
$nextCheck+=1000; "      
in place of     
"$check+1000;"

Answer (score 2):

Do not generate an array.  Do not use a loop.  Use math to determine the upper limit of the range, then subtract `999` from that number -- done.

*my snippet assumes we are only dealing with positive values between 1 and 100000.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jDbsp))

```
$tests = [1, 999, 1000, 50001, 100000, 2999];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $upper = intval(($test - 1) / 1000) * 1000 + 1000;
    echo "$test is between " . ($upper - 999) . " and $upper\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 is between 1 and 1000
999 is between 1 and 1000
1000 is between 1 and 1000
50001 is between 50001 and 51000
100000 is between 99001 and 100000
2999 is between 2001 and 3000
```

Formula Breakdown:

```
intval(            #3) remove decimals from difference
    ($test - 1)    #1) subtract one
    / 1000         #2) divide by 1000
)
* 1000             #4) multiply integer by 1000
+ 1000             #5) add 1000
```

Comment: @Jestin the answer that you accepted is not direct, it is an inefficient "guess and check" technique.  Why would anyone not want to use my mathematical one-liner?  You even state under the answer that it doesn't work -- why would you give it a green tick?!  Now researchers will be biased toward a suboptimal answer.

Comment: This should be marked as best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide the number by `1000` since you have a 1000 interval range in a consecutive way.

The `quotient * 1000 + 1` is your start value for the interval with an exceptional corner case of a number divisible by 1000, which would just be the border end for an interval.

```
<?php

$tests = [1,999,1000,50001,100000,2999];

foreach($tests as $test_case){
    $quotient = intval($test_case / 1000);
    if($test_case % 1000 === 0){
        $start = $test_case - 1000 + 1;
        echo "$test_case : Range: ($start - $test_case)",PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        $start = $quotient * 1000 + 1;
        $end = ($quotient + 1) * 1000;
        echo "$test_case : Range: ($start - $end)",PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 : Range: (1 - 1000)
999 : Range: (1 - 1000)
1000 : Range: (1 - 1000)
50001 : Range: (50001 - 51000)
100000 : Range: (99001 - 100000)
2999 : Range: (2001 - 3000)
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/apbqV